# Reaching chart from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a chart on form1 and I am trying to reach that chart form form2. For example getting the name of the series. It gives me this 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Chart's modifier is Public (I try also internal). I don't understand why. Any ideas

```
TrackerV2 tv2 = ActiveForm as TrackerV2; //reaching main form with this
MessageBox.Show(tv2.chartMonthlyReport.Series[0].Name.ToString());
```

Comment: I don't think you supplied enough of the code to know what it is you doing, IE are you sure you have the right form using ActiveForm?  Wouldn't the active form be the one you are running this code from?....

Comment: ActiveForm probably isn't a TrackerV2 form.  Use the actual reference you used when you created the TrackerV2 form.

Comment: This code from form2, form1 is TrackerV2 which is activeform. There is a button on form1 when I clicked it it opens the form2 with .Showdialog();. And then I am click the button on form2 it runs the code I shared

Comment: @Belnord - Add an event to `form2` such as `public event EventHandler DisplaySeriesName;` and then subscribe to this event before calling `ShowDialog()`. Then when you click the button on `form2` you just raise the event.

Comment: Not enough code. Show a minimal reproducible example of how to launch both forms. Then we can guide you better.

Comment: "This code from form2, form1 is TrackerV2 which is activeform". No It is not.  ActiveForm is returning the form you click the button that has the code IE Form2, you click the button on Form2 which is the active form.

Comment: So I solved it (i guess). Problem is in form1 I am creating this in public SpendForm spendForm = new SpendForm(); (this is form2) before. If I create this in button which calls the form2 then I call the names of series. Thanks for the ideas and helps guys

Comment: @Belnord - It's not a good idea to expose forms as public fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of how to use an event to signal back to `form1`.

```
void Main()
{
    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Show();
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button Button1;
    private Chart chartMonthlyReport;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.Button1 = new Button() { Text = "Open Form 2", Width = 256, };
        this.Button1.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            var form2 = new Form2();
            form2.DisplaySeriesName += (s2, e2) =>
                MessageBox.Show(chartMonthlyReport.Series[0].Name);
            form2.ShowDialog();
        };
        this.chartMonthlyReport = new Chart();
        this.chartMonthlyReport.Series.Add(new Series() { Name = "Monthly" });
        this.Controls.Add(this.Button1);
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    private Button Button1;
    public event EventHandler DisplaySeriesName;

    public Form2()
    {
        this.Button1 = new Button() { Text = "Display Series Name", Width = 256, };
        this.Button1.Click += (s, e) =>
            this.DisplaySeriesName?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        this.Controls.Add(this.Button1);
    }
}
```

When I run this I get this:

[image]